# how to print a value in a dictionary in a list sorted by a different value

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a list of dictionaries, and each dictionary has multiple values in it.
the values share the same keys across all of the dictionaries, so they can be sorted by the lambda function.
i need to sort the dictionaries by a specific value, like 'water'
then i need to take the sorted list of dictionaries, and print the 'rent' value of the dictionary with the lowest 'water' value.

```
#dictionaries
dict0 = {'rent' : 5, 'water' : 2, 'lawncare' : 1}
dict1 = {'rent' : 8, 'water' : 3, 'lawncare' : 4}
dict2 = {'rent' : 6, 'water' : 4, 'lawncare' : 3}

#dictionaries in a list
list0 = [dict0, dict1, dict2]

#print the dictionary with the lowest 'water' value
print((sorted(list0, key = lambda item: item['water'])))

# how do i print the 'rent' value of the dictionary with the lowest 'water' value?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference, it is useful and [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to look for solutions yourself first. For example, in this case: you might try to think clearly about how you learned that there is such a function as `sorted`; then, go back to that place and look for something else more directly suitable for the task. Alternately, you could try putting something like `python lowest value in list` into a search engine.

Comment: Usually `dict0`, `dict1` ... `dictN` is  a marker of bad architecture. Normally it should be a nested dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to sort the list of dictionaries. Instead you can use `min()` function with custom `key=` function:

```py
dict0 = {"rent": 5, "water": 2, "lawncare": 1}
dict1 = {"rent": 8, "water": 3, "lawncare": 4}
dict2 = {"rent": 6, "water": 4, "lawncare": 3}

# dictionaries in a list
list0 = [dict0, dict1, dict2]

lowest_water_dict = min(list0, key=lambda d: d["water"])
print(lowest_water_dict["rent"])
```

Prints:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sorted list by the `'water'` like what you did, so the first dictionary in the list has the lowest `'water'` value. Just take it's `'rent'`:

```
# dictionaries
dict0 = {'rent': 5, 'water': 2, 'lawncare': 1}
dict1 = {'rent': 8, 'water': 3, 'lawncare': 4}
dict2 = {'rent': 6, 'water': 4, 'lawncare': 3}

list0 = [dict0, dict1, dict2]
sorted_list = sorted(list0, key=lambda item: item['water'])

print(sorted_list)
print(sorted_list[0]['rent'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as you already sorted it, you can collect the first element from that sorted list (which is the smallest water water one) and then search for the key of rent in that first selected dictionary. Would look like this.

```
print((sorted(list0, key = lambda item: item['water'])[0]['rent']))
```